# How to only subscribe to an observable after its data was fetched in Angular/NgRx?

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx

I have a component where I wish to fetch some data from the backend when a button has been clicked, and based on that data navigate to the correct page.

I have the following code in the `ngOnInit()` function:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select(getUsers)
  .pipe()
  .subscribe((users) => {
    this.navigateToNextStep(users.length > 0);  // navigates to correct page based on the boolean parameter
  });
}
```

And I have the following function:

```
nextClicked() {
  this.store.dispatch(MyActions.getUsers());
}
```

The idea is that I would subscribe to the observable user list when creating the component, and then fetch the list when the button was clicked, triggering the subscription. However, the subscription gets triggered as soon as I enter the page, even though the user list was not fetched.

What is the correct way to achieve my goal where the navigation would only happen when the user list was actively fetched by the click? Also notice that the user list gets saved in the store, so I need to avoid any unintended behaviour in the case where the user returns to the page after navigating away.

Comment: But you're subscribing in the `ngOnInit`? If you wish to navigate only after the click, the entire subscription block from `ngOnInit` could be moved to the `nextClicked()` handler.

Comment: @MichaelD You're probably correct. However, it wouldn't actually solve the issue since the subscription block and fetching of the data are asynchronous. That means that the subscription gets triggered as soon as `nextClicked()` is called - before the backend service has a chance to return with the data.
What I need is a way to subscribe AFTER the data was fetched.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with NgRX. Please say which statement here returns the data from the backend service. In the current code, the subscription `next` callback will **only** be triggered when the statement `this.store.select(getUsers)` emits a notification.

Comment: The actual fetching of the data from the backend happens elsewhere. When the action `MyActions.getUsers()` is dispatched it is caught by an so-called Effect, which fetches the data via a Service. Then the data is passed to a Reducer which updates the state. Then a notification is sent to all that observe this data via the `this.store.select(getUsers)` selector. My problem is that there is seemingly a notification emitted immediately when subscribing, and at this point my data has not been fetched yet.

Comment: @MichaelD is right, you should subscribe in nextClicked(). can you also share the code with the notification? I suppose you'll have to move it so it happens after the back-end call.

Comment: @DPro I had actually tried it, and it gave me the samme issue as described in my comment to him above. And I don't have specific code for notifications. It's all part of NgRx.

Comment: maybe you need `.pipe(filter(data => !!data))` to skip initial empty value from the store?

Comment: @DPro I got it working using a filter. Perhaps you could write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.pipe(filter(data => !!data))` to skip the initial empty value from the store